# Game object not saving state in MonoGame

Tags: c#, monogame

In the game logic part of my game, where you check for input, why is the state my object had before is not being used in further evaluations of my function?

My game class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MonoRPG
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


        public Game1()
            : base()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            Player playerObject = new Player(this, this.Content, this.spriteBatch);
            KeyboardState oldState;
            KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("right key pressed");
            }

            oldState = newState;


            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            renderMap createMap = new renderMap(this, this.Content, this.spriteBatch);
            Player playerObject = new Player(this, this.Content, this.spriteBatch);

            createMap.RenderMap();
            playerObject.drawPlayer();
            playerObject.positionX = playerObject.positionX + 10;

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

And my player class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MonoRPG
{
    public class Player
    {
        public int positionX = 0;
        public int positionY = 0;

        Game1 draw = new Game1();
        ContentManager gameContent;
        SpriteBatch playerSprites;
        KeyboardState oldState;


        public Player(Game1 canvas, ContentManager content, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            draw = canvas;
            gameContent = content;
            playerSprites = spriteBatch;
        }

        public Player()
        {

        }


        public void drawPlayer()
        {
            Texture2D playerTexture = gameContent.Load<Texture2D>("player/player.png");

            playerSprites.Begin();
            playerSprites.Draw(playerTexture, new Vector2(positionX, positionY), Color.Red);
            playerSprites.End();
        }

        public void playerMove(KeyboardState keyState, KeyboardState oldState)
        {
            positionX = positionX + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

The drawing is working fine, but the position of the rectangle sprite I'm using for the player won't change. Is the problem related to how I'm creating the objects? I tried declaring outside the functions, but then I can't use the `this` keyword. How can I call the functions on my existing objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize (create) objects in the `Initialize` or `LoadContent` methods. The object should be created only once, not every update of the game. The `Initialize` and `LoadContent` happens only once, at the startup of the game (the `Initialize` first, the `LoadContent` when you call `base.Initialize()`).

When you put code in the `Update` method, it is executed at every update (usually, every frame) of the game. Your code should look more like this

```
Player player;
KeyboardState oldState; // player and oldState belongs to the whole game

protected override void Initialize() {
    // remember that spriteBatch is still null here
    player = new Player(this, Content, spriteBatch);
    // the line below initializes the spriteBatch
    // check the comments to see why this exact code won't work
    base.Initialize();
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
    KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState(); // newState belongs to this exact update only

    if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right)) {
        player.playerMove(newState, oldState); // not sure why you wish to pass these arguments?
    }

    oldState = newState;
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    renderMap createMap = new renderMap(this, this.Content, this.spriteBatch);

    createMap.RenderMap();

    // the player here is the same player in the Update method
    player.drawPlayer();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: When i initialize them in initialize function i start getting nullreference exceptions in Player.cs saying that playerSprites isnt set to an instance of an object?

Comment: @user3585434 as I said, the `LoadContent` executes AFTER the `Initialize`. You can move the `new Player()` ro the `LoadContent` or the `new SpriteBatch()` to the `Initialize` to create the sprite batch before creating the player. Anyway, it is pretty bad practice to pass sprite batches when creating new game objects (pass them only in the `Draw` method).

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, Thank you very much i will keep thi in mind!